# Keep RecylerView adapter checkbox checked if user come back to the activity by clicking on same button[Kotlin]

Tags: java, android, checkbox, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have activity one where having a empty `textview` user has click on this `textview` to select location from list of location so for that when user click on select location `textview` it will open list of location with `checkbox`.

When user select location(can select multiple location) and click on done then all selected location will be showing on activity one `textView` with all selected checked `textview` value now when user click on same `textview` to add more location then on `recylerview` list all previous checked item should be checked. I'm not getting all previous selected checkbox.

I'm not getting how to achieve this. I need all old `checkbox` should be selected and user can select some more new checkbox if click on same `textview`. Please help me to get this. Java code will be also helpful for me

Below is my recylerView Adapter code:-

```
    class SelectMedicineAdapter (val medicineList : ArrayList<String>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()  {
    var selectedCheckBoxMedicineList : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.textViewSelectMedicineName.text = medicineList.get(position)

        holder.itemView.checkboxSelectMedicine.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            val itemText = medicineList.get(position)

            if (isChecked) {
                selectedCheckBoxMedicineList.add(itemText)

            } else {
                selectedCheckBoxMedicineList.remove(itemText)
            }


        }
    }

    fun getSelectedMedicineList(): ArrayList<String> {
        return selectedCheckBoxMedicineList
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return medicineList.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(holder: ViewGroup, p1: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val v= (LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_select_medicine_adapter,holder,false))
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        var textViewSelectMedicineName = itemView.textViewSelectMedicineName
        var imageViewPlusButton = itemView.imageViewPlusButton
        var imageViewMinusButton = itemView.imageViewMinusButton
        var checkboxSelectMedicine = itemView.checkboxSelectMedicine

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update views with their items state (selected or not).

In onSaveInstanceState of your activity/fragment where your adapter is you should write adapters state (which items are selected (`getSelectedMedicineList`)) to the bundle.

Whenever your fragment/activity is restored just update adapter with data you saved `restoreSelectedMedicineList(selectedCheckBoxMedicineList: ArrayList<String>)`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.textViewSelectMedicineName.text = medicineList.get(position)

    holder.itemView.checkboxSelectMedicine.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
    if(selectedCheckBoxMedicineList.contains(itemText)) {
        holder.itemView.setChecked(true)
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setChecked(false)
    }

    holder.itemView.checkboxSelectMedicine.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            val itemText = medicineList.get(position)



        if (isChecked) {
            selectedCheckBoxMedicineList.add(itemText)

        } else {
            selectedCheckBoxMedicineList.remove(itemText)
        }


    }
}

fun restoreSelectedMedicineList(selectedCheckBoxMedicineList: ArrayList<String>) {
    this.selectedCheckBoxMedicineList = selectedCheckBoxMedicineList
    notifyDataSetInvalidated()        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start an `Activity`, it has no knowledge of what is the state of your data. You need to provide the state for the `Activity`.
By which I mean when the user selects his/her desired locations and goes back to `Activity One` you to need hold on to these selected locations and when the user again wants to update the locations you need to pass these previously selected locations to the second `Activity` and then update the `RecyclerView`'s **backing data** accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

in your list you do maintain a boolean field when select check box then selected position value is true, and notify data and inside onbind viewholder you check first which position is true. if true then show selected checkbox otherwise unselect.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm working with an app, I have faced same problem and also I needed that checked boxes even app closes. So I used **SharedPreferences** to stored and retrieve values that will indicates states of check boxes then I can easily specify the states of all element. So if you face same problem and have no solution you can use this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the model class with a flag on every tick and untick. Check this flag to tick and untick logic for restoring the checkbox state.